# Firefox/IE showing dark color when using dark themes in Windows

Tags: windows, firefox, internet-explorer

I use dark themes (totally black) on my computer. In Chrome I can work with no problem. How I can get Firefox to work normally? The same thing happens in IE. Is there any global setting in both IE and Firefox to prevent this from happening?

Comment: I means totally black background in firefox

Comment: Have you searched for some config in `about:config`?
There is a config: `background color`

Comment: bro, it's not worked on my side. I have tried to change them all. any sollution. work fine if I am using Classic mode.